# How to mock dispatch methods in ReduxAction from flutter package `async_redux`

Tags: flutter, redux, mocking, async-redux

I am developing an android / ios application in flutter, and I have chosen to use redux for my state management.

I am writing unit tests for my redux actions, which have been implemented using the [async_redux](https://pub.dev/packages/async_redux/#async_redux) package.

I am following the excellent guidelines set out for testing by the author of the package, but I am not sure how to mock the dispatch of further actions from my action under test.

For example, the below `LogoutAction` dispatchs a `DeleteDatabaseAction` and waits for it to complete:

```dart
class LogoutAction extends ReduxAction<AppState> {
  @override
  Future<AppState> reduce() async {
    await dispatchFuture(DeleteDatabaseAction());
    return AppState.initialState();
  }
}

class DeleteDatabaseAction extends ReduxAction<AppState> {
  @override
  FutureOr<AppState> reduce() {
    throw StateError(
      'Unwanted call to runtime implementation of DeleteDatabaseAction',
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
void main() {
  final store = Store<AppState>(initialState: AppState(loggedIn: true));
  final storeTester = StoreTester.from(store);

  test('Logout action should return correct state and not throw StateError', () async {
    storeTester.dispatch(LogoutAction());

    TestInfo<AppState> info = await storeTester.wait(LogoutAction);

    expect(info.state.loggedIn, false);
  });
}
```

I want to test only the action under test, and stub out all further action calls.

i.e. How can I mock / stub the `dispatch` and `dispatchFuture` methods on `ReduxAction`, so that the runtime `DeleteDatabaseAction` implementation is not run?

So far I have attempted:

- Inject `DeleteDatabaseAction` using get_it and inject a mock during test

  - I have 100+ actions that will now need to be added to my context
  - Some actions have parameters that change based on where they are called from, so cannot be registered at app startup
- Subclass `Store`, override the above methods and use the subclass in my test here `final store = Store<AppState>(initialState: AppState(loggedIn: true))`

  - I will not be able to dispatch my action under test, as it uses the same store in the async_redux test implementation
  - Here: `storeTester.dispatch(LogoutAction());`
- Create a separate `Dispatcher` implementation, inject this and override with a mock during tests

  - This will work, but it is new framework, I can go this route but now I am deviating from the well documented framework provided by asyn_redux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't available when you asked this question. But now the answer is here: https://pub.dev/packages/async_redux#mocking-actions-and-reducers

To mock an action and its reducer, start by creating a `MockStore` in your tests, instead of a regular `Store`. The `MockStore` has a `mocks` parameter which is a map where the keys are action types, and the values are the mocks. For example:

```dart
var store = MockStore<AppState>(
  initialState: initialState,  
  mocks: {
     MyAction1 : ...
     MyAction2 : ...
     ...
  },
);
```

However, there are other ways:

1. As you said, use `get_it` or some other dependency injection code to inject the http client into the action reducer. This works well.
2. Use a DAO. For example:

   ```
   class DeleteDatabaseAction extends ReduxAction<AppState> {
      @override
      Future<AppState> reduce() {
         await dao.deleteDatabase();
         return null;
      }
   ```

   Then you can mock the DAO itself, or inject the DAO via `get_it`. You can also make the dao a getter to some `BaseAction` (that extends `ReduxAction`) and inject it there.